# Querying timespan in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: timespan, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to query, among other things, based on a timespan during a day. From, say, 08:00 to 13:00.

Normally in SQL, you'd do it using DATEPART(hh, elem.time), but apparently DATEPART isn't supported in DocumentDB.

Can't seem to find anything about it in the documentation and can't seem to find any help elsewhere.

Datetime looks like this: `2017-09-28T14:12:43.1655795Z`

Anyone have any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show an example document with a datetime field? That will tell us if you are using ISO-8601 strings and how you are specifying time zone. If you are using numbers, the approach will be different.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone Oh, wow, I read your reply and said to myself that I would reply when I got home. Then I forgot and fell asleep, and then life kind of got in the way. 

I've added an example date to the OP. Yeah ,it's ISO-8601 format.